# Count unique rows in matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

Consider the following array:

```
a = [1 2 3;
     1 1 1;
     1 2 3]
```

How can I count the number of unique rows in this array? The answer in the example is **2**, because the `[1 2 3]` row is repeated twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [**`unique`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) with the `'rows'` property to get the unique rows and count them by obtaining the `size` in row direction of the output.

```
uniquerows = size( unique(a,'rows'), 1)
```

Alternative you could count the second output of `unique` with [**`numel`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/numel.html):

```
[~,c] = unique(a,'rows')
uniquerows  = numel(c)
```

Answer (score 1):

One-liner solution with `sum`, `any`, `diff` & `sortrows` -

```
count_unqrows = sum(any(diff(sortrows(a),1),2))+1
```

---

Benchmarks -

Benchmarking Code to compare all solution approaches posted so far:

```
%// Input
a = randi(1000,5000,5000);

%// Warm up tic/toc.
for k = 1:50000
    tic(); elapsed = toc();
end

disp('-------------- With SUM, ANY, DIFF, SORTROWS')
tic
out1 = sum(any(diff(sortrows(a),1),2))+1;
toc, clear out1

disp('-------------- With UNIQUE, NUMEL')
tic
[~,c] = unique(a,'rows');
out2  = numel(c);
toc, clear out2

disp('-------------- With UNIQUE, SIZE')
tic
out3 = size( unique(a,'rows'), 1);
toc, clear out3
```

Results:

```
-------------- With SUM, ANY, DIFF, SORTROWS
Elapsed time is 0.502803 seconds.
-------------- With UNIQUE, NUMEL
Elapsed time is 1.237495 seconds.
-------------- With UNIQUE, SIZE
Elapsed time is 1.155051 seconds.
```

Comment: Comparing my first solution with yours, would have been fairer - but yours is faster in any case ;) +1

Comment: @thewaywewalk Well there is a slight improvement with it, it seems. Added that too! :)